# download wso2 identity server by using wget in unix

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am setting up WSO2 Identity server in my AWS EC2 instance.
What is the URL to WGET so that i can download the installation.I cant find the URL in the website anywhere
The version of identity server is 5.3.0 and I am using the prepackaged version so that i can use it as the key manager. I tried some urls from the download links.But whats the official page which tells which urls to use?Is there a product page which tells how to download in Unix box
How can i download in Unix box?which URL to use ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below for downloading latest Identity Server release.

```
wget --user-agent="testuser" --referer="http://connect.wso2.com/wso2/getform/reg/new_product_download"  http://product-dist.wso2.com/products/identity-server/5.3.0/wso2is-5.3.0.zip
```

For latest API Manager, use below

```
wget --user-agent="testuser" --referer="http://connect.wso2.com/wso2/getform/reg/new_product_download"  http://product-dist.wso2.com/products/api-manager/2.1.0/wso2am-2.1.0.zip
```

Comment: where in the official doc i can find this?